# Kendo Grid Paging doesn't work in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, pagination, grid

I am trying to bind a Kendo Grid in Asp.Net MVC but the paging doesn't work. The PageSize and the Total records are correct, the problem is that it isn't possible to navigate to the next page. All the buttons are displayed but they are disabled.

The view's code is:

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("PartListGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Title("Id").Visible (false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).Title("Quantity")).Width(130);
            columns.Bound(p => p.PartNumber).Title("Part Number").Width(130);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.Id))
            .PageSize(5)
            .ServerOperation(false)
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Render();                                        
%>
```

The Controller's code :

```
public ActionResult GetPartListInfo(string id)
{                 
    List<PartListViewModel> partList = new List<PartListViewModel>();
    XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext();
    f1_workorder workOrder = xrmServiceContext.f1_workorderSet.Where(i => i.Id == new Guid(workOrderId)).FirstOrDefault();
    PartListViewModel partViewModel = null;

    foreach (f1_workorderproduct workorderproduct in xrmServiceContext.f1_workorderproductSet.Where(i => i.f1_WorkOrder.Id == workOrder.Id).ToList())
    {
        Product product = xrmServiceContext.ProductSet.Where(j => j.Id == workorderproduct.f1_Product.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        partViewModel = new PartListViewModel();
        partViewModel.Id = workorderproduct.f1_Product.Id.ToString();  
        partViewModel.Quantity = workorderproduct.f1_EstimateQuantity.GetValueOrDefault(0);
        partViewModel.PartNumber = workorderproduct.f1_name;                              

        partList.Add(partViewModel);     
    }    

    return View("PartList",partList);
}
```

Any advice is appreciated!
Thank you very much for your help!

Mimi

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have to throw in a data source read configuration so that the dataset can fetch the data on paging when needed.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    ...
    .Read(read => read.Action("YourAction", "YourController))
    ...
```

Comment: Check your ID field using F12 and see if ID is being used in the request. I would bet that may not be sent.

Comment: I do not think this line is required .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.Id)) .It is only required when you are using the Update/Insert/Delete commands of the grid.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer but when I call the method from Controller
.Read(read => read.Action("GetParts", "Claim", new { id = Model.WoId }) 

I don't see anything in the grid; The grid isn't bound because I can't pass the Model in the parameter like before : 
<% Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
 .Name("PartListGrid")...
Instead I pass the Grid type like so:     
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModels.PartListViewModel>()
 .Name("PartListGrid")...